# How to toggle src attribute of script when user click element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I use bootstrap 3.3.7 in my Django project. I have modal with `<textarea>`. Inside that textarea in the corner I put an icon. Below is a picture of my textarea.
[image]
When the user clicks the icon I change the textarea size to full screen of the browser. Also, I use [autosize](https://github.com/jackmoore/autosize) plugin on my textarea which adjusts the  height of the textarea to fit text.

In normal situations (when textarea is small) I need to use autosize plugin. When I click icon and change textarea to full screen I don't need to use this plugin.

**Question**: How to toogle *src* attribute of script when I click icon?

**P.S.** I have little conflict with autosize plugin when textarea in full size mode. Cause when I started to write in textarea in full size mode autosize plugin change it's height. For that's why I want to cancel this plugin when textarea in fullscreen mode.

```js
autosize(document.querySelectorAll('#body')); // Autosize for textarea with "body" id

$('.textarea-icon').click(function() {
  $(".textarea-icon").toggleClass("fa-expand fa-compress")
  $(".textarea-wrapper").toggleClass('textarea-wrapper-fullscreen')
  $("#body").toggleClass('textarea-fullscreen')
  $(".modal-dialog").toggleClass('modal-dialog-fullscreen')
  $(".textarea-icon").toggleClass('textarea-icon-fullscreen')
});
```

```css
.dashboard-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#dashboard-content {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 51px;
}

.textarea-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.textarea-wrap .textarea-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  color: #BDBDBD;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer
}

.textarea-wrap .textarea-icon:hover {
  color: #757575;
  outline: none;
}

.textarea-wrap.textarea-wrap-fullscreen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.textarea-wrap textarea.textarea-fullscreen {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/autosize@4.0.0/dist/autosize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dashboard-wrapper">
  <div id="dashboard-content">
    <div class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <form method="post" action="">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="body">Discription</label>
              <div class="textarea-wrapper">
                <textarea name="body" class="form-control" id="body"></textarea>
                <i class="fa fa-arrows textarea-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script id="" src="{% static 'js/autosize.js'%}"></script>
```

**EDIT**:

```
autosize(document.querySelectorAll('#body')); // Autosize to textarea

$('.textarea-wrapper .fa-expand').click(function() {
    autosize.destroy(document.querySelectorAll('#body')); // Destroy Autosize to textarea when user click icon
});

$('.textarea-icon').click(function() {
   $(".textarea-icon").toggleClass("fa-expand fa-compress") // Change Icon Picture
   $(this).closest('.textarea-wrapper').toggleClass('fullscreen') // Change textarea size
});

$('.textarea-wrapper .fa-compress').click(function() { // DONT WORK
   autosize(document.querySelectorAll('#body'));
})
```

Comment: Removing the script after it has run won't disable the plugin when fullscreen.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with bootstrap or django

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you right, you just want use autosize.destroy() on appropriate element when you enlarged it (i.e. in "click" event, when you change your textarea behaviour). Basically it should disable plugin working on your textarea.

(minor side comment) 
Apart from that I would vote for adding some particular class to the wrapper around textarea and then adjusting css according to that class, so you would avoid a few queries to DOM in "click" function.

Comment: RE: side comment .... for sure the way to go... https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/e2hnhtu3 - also, if you are going to use jQuery, you may as well use it for all your 'queries' vs document.querySelectorAll('#body') --- also... look into some other elements besides 'div' so your markup can be more expressive. : )

Comment: I am little bit confused from your answers. Can you tell your ideas in more detail, pls? Do you have any ideas about that? In normal situations (when textarea is small) I need to use autosize plugin. When I click icon and change textarea to full screen I don't need to use this plugin.

Comment: From documentation I found this command: `autosize.destroy(document.querySelectorAll('#body'));` How to toggle autosize by clicking the icon? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check my post again pls. `EDIT` part. Last part of my code dont work. I think cause DOM dont see `fa-compress` after icon class changed. What can you advice me?